# How to display lockscreen background image a bit longer when pressing Win+L?

Tags: 17.10, lock-screen, wayland

When I lock my screen with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> the
lockscreen's background image is shown for just about a second or so
(presumably less) and then the screen turns off.

Is there a way to keep the lockscreen image for a while, say 5 minutes
or so before the screen turns black?

I mean, what's the purpose of configuring an image when only flies or
hummingbirds can actually recognize it?

I'm on U17.10 with Wayland.