# How to keep lock screen alive?

Tags: monitor, lock-screen

When I lock my desktop, the monitor goes to sleep. But I want to keep the monitor active and never go to sleep.

Comment: I asked [almost the same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1016959/504066) some weeks ago. And was rewarded the [_tumbleweed award_](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) for it. Fingers crossed! ;-)

Comment: If you are running Gnome 3, have you tried 'Settings->Power->Blank screen->never'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent monitor from losing signal after screen saver / lock activates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696738/prevent-monitor-from-losing-signal-after-screen-saver-lock-activates)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be part of the

> sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
>
> gnome-screensaver-command -l

command and I don't see an easy way to disable it.
ie **gnome-screensaver-command -l** brings up the lock screen and also initiates the screen blanking.

Notice that initially when the lockscreen is activated it starts to dim almost immediately.
If you come out of the screen blanking by moving the mouse or hitting a key it will then
activate screen blanking according to your brightness and lock setting.

Answer (score 1):

This answer did the trick for me on Ubuntu 20.04. The monitor shows a black screen but stays active. https://askubuntu.com/a/700163/768152